# SharePoint REST API to get Discussion List Questions and Replies separately

Tags: sharepoint

Can anyone please tell me how to get replies and discussions separately using  rest api in sharepoint 2013.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you can already do, the results returned, and what you'd like to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the list of questions.

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$filter=ContentType eq 'Discussion'
```

To get the list of replies.

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$filter=ContentType eq 'Message'
```

Update:

Try /_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('DiscussionBoard')/items?$select=Id,Title,Body,Author/Name&$expand=Author&$filter=ContentType eq 'Discussion'

Comment: Thanks, It works great. Still I am not able to get "Created By" value. Is there a way to get that??